# Finding a property value in an array of object based on another property value

Tags: arrays, prototype, array.prototype.map

I have the following array

```
const arrayOfObject = [{
      name: 'Mike',
      age: '38',
    }, {
      name: 'Russell',
      age: '42',
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      age: '26',
    }, ];
```

and I want to find the age of 'Russell' for instance.

If I use .find() I manage to get the whole object

```
const employeeAge = arrayOfObject.find((item) => item.name === 'Russell')
```

Is it possible to do it in one line?

Comment: `const employeeAge = arrayOfObject.find(item => item.name === 'Russell').age`

Comment: it's giving me undefined

Comment: Not sure how that's possible. If you can get the whole object using `find`, and the object has an `age` property, then referring to the age property of the object will return the age. If you get undefined then the second part is not true.

Comment: Added some logs and just using `find` I actually get `[object Object]`. Do I need to do `map` after that?